# How to change the Windows XP console font?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, console

I have been using Cleartype and Vista fonts on Windows XP for quite a while now. I love the Consolas font for working with source code. I would love to have it as the font of my Windows console (command) window too. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See also [How to set the command prompt font on XP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40055/how-to-set-the-command-prompt-font-on-xp/) on Server Fault.

Comment: Well ... you can always try something like this to replace your old `cmd` : http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- Create a backup of the windows registry.
- On regedit, navigate to

  `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`
- Right click on the right pane, select `New` -> `String value`.
- Write `00` as the entry name.
- Right click on the new entry, click on `Modify`.
- Write the name of the desired font on the `Value` data field. That value should match one of the entries on `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
- If you want to add additional fonts, repeat the previous steps, adding a `0` to the entry name each time (that is, the third entry should be `000` and so on).
- Reboot your PC to apply the changes.
- Open a console window, right click on the title bar, select `Properties`.
- Select the `Font` tab. The new fonts should appear on the list.

Before doing any of this, please read the article "[Why are console windows limited to Lucida Console and raster fonts?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070516-00/?p=26843)", which explains in great detail why you shouldn't do that anyway.

Comment: There's this Microsoft support article which adds a bit more detail about limitations too: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q247815

Comment: +1 for the link to that blog! A must-read indeed.

Comment: It is terrible that this works.

Comment: Note that code page in Command Prompt limited the choice of font. Find active code page first by `chcp`. Then try using UTF-8 code page (PERMANENT change!) `chcp 65001` to reveal the font in the list.

Comment: (1) The link in Ant's comment is broken.  (2) On my Windows 7 system, I already have a `00` = `Consolas` value (I don't remember putting it there).  (Yes, I know, the question is about Windows XP.)  (3) This answer seems to be suggesting using `000`, `0000`, `00000`, ..., if you're adding many entries.  While you probably *shouldn't* be adding a ***lot*** of fonts, a naming scheme of `000`, `001`, `002` would seem to be more extensible/sustainable.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple registry tweak.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
```

Add a string value (REG_SZ) with the name 00 and put Consolas in the 'data' field.

You will then need to reboot your PC, and change the default within command prompt.

Start -> Run -> Cmd.

Right click the title of the window -> Properties -> Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/). It is way superior to the "DOS box". It's better than Console too.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the instance.
Another console terminal replacement: https://eugeny.github.io/terminus/
Based on the Electron supported from Windows 7 and higher.
But neverless you can try to replace the Electron with the Windows XP version: https://discuss.atom.io/t/electron-windows-can-support-xp/29428