# How to change the cmd.exe font?

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-registry, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the Windows console font?](https://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-console-font)

Firstly: *I have tried the options dialog for it (the one that Windows shows) and I don't want that*.
The default windows option dialog for it only allows two fonts: "Raster"(Fixedsys) and Lucida Console. However, I want to use Consolas (which is a really chic font). I've tried messing with the registry options for the current user "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" but it doesn't seem to work. Help appreciated.

Comment: Wow.  It is ridiculous you have to hack the registry to use a different font.

Comment: wfaulk: Most Windows users will probably consider it ridiculous to have to hack `~/.foorc` to use a different font, too.

Comment: @wfaulk: Most Windows users won't even be able to figure out why the file "doesn't have a name"

Comment: Duplicate, with an important warning in a referenced blog, at "How to change the Windows console font?" at http://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-console-font/5079#5079

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're changing the wrong key. Navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont\
```

Right click in the blank white space in the right pane and select **New -> String Value**.

Edit the value to these settings:

```
Name: 00
Data: Consolas
```

Open command prompt and you should be able to switch to Consolas font in the properties. A reboot is essential for it to appear properly. I'd also recommend to turn on cleartype to make it look smoother. Consolas looks best with cleartype on.

Comment: That shows the font, yes, but then consolas starts looking like Lucida Console. (:?)

Comment: Some sources claim you have to *reboot* before it will work properly.

Comment: yep you need to reboot, answer updated.

Comment: @wfaulk, you only need to open a new console for it show up in the font list of the *Properties* dialog, but you need to reboot for it actually take effect, otherwise changing the font to the newly added one doesn’t actually change the font.

Comment: Note that the "name needs to be incrimented with “0″ for each additional font." So if I wanted to add a second font, the name would be "000". - http://blog.wolffmyren.com/2009/02/26/necessary-criteria-for-fonts-to-be-available-in-a-command-window/

Answer (score 7):

Not really an 'answer' per se, but [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) is a delicious wrapper to cmd that allows much greater choice over how it looks. It's also tabbed, and supports transparency (if that's your thing)
I could also give you an ahk script to make it whoosh down like the console from [insert most FPS titles here], if that'd sweeten the deal ;)

Comment: Why the downvote, voter? I can't get better if nobody tells me how :'(

Comment: It wasn't mine, but, "If somebody wanted the answer to a different question surely they'd go into a different question?" ;-)

Comment: Ah, but it DOES let you change the font, and much better than the official shell :P

Answer (score 1):

I had to use [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) in order to get this 'feature'. It is basically a cmd.exe replacement for Windows. Besides configuring advanced fonts and colours, it has a pile of other features you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman describes essentially the same solution as John T's here:

[Using Consolas as the Windows Console Font](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingConsolasAsTheWindowsConsoleFont.aspx)

Comment: It would be better to provide instructions than just a link.

Comment: It's against the SU-creed to just post links. What happens if/when that site dies? Your answer dies with it! Post instructions (with a link as reference, if you like), so it'll be accessible to anybody reading it.