# How to change windows console font with nerd or powerline?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, cmd.exe, console

First, this question is not duplicate of 
[How to change the Windows XP console font?](https://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-console-font), and 
[How to change the cmd.exe font?](https://superuser.com/questions/55318/how-to-change-the-cmd-exe-font)

---

I want to change console font from

[image]

to powerline font: (can show vim-theme, bash-theme)

https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts

https://github.com/powerline/fonts

---

The turorial is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/), but edit regedit not work.

Then I see

> What Fonts Can I Enable?
>
> The command prompt will only accept fonts that are fixed-width, so
>   don’t even bother trying to enable Comic Sans =) I started looking
>   around on various font websites and found a few fonts that worked,
>   like this White Rabbit font that has a fun look:

So, how could I distinguish a font is fixed-width and windows console compatible? Is there any easy way to set console font(powerline group)?

PS: I know other shell such as ConEmu, git-bash(mintty) and others do support this.Because I like using ConEmu in mintty mode(though working in cmd mode), which contain font problem and have to fix by this way.(Auther says that is not his problem, so I have to work it out by myself)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?… I have the exact same problem. ☹