# Fixedsys as Command Prompt font (Fallout theme)

Tags: windows, fonts, prompt, cmd.exe

I'm trying to configure my Command Prompt to look like the terminals from Fallout 3.

I managed to extract the colour values from the included image, which I am very happy with. (If anyone wants to know:

```
Values      -   R   G   B
Text        -  041 225 140
Background  -  014 046 032
```

)

So, now I want to change Command Prompt's font to match. [This website](http://fallout.answers.wikia.com/wiki/FO3_%28PC%29_Looking_for_actual_Terminal_Font_Location,_either_using_G.e.c.k._-_Used_the_.BSA_extractor_but_the_xml_used_only_shows_adjustments_i.e._height,color_blah_blah_blah._Anyone_have_a_location_or_Link_for_a_%22close_font_match%22) says that a close match is Fixedsys, which I don't disagree with. I noticed that Windows 7 already includes "Fixedsys Regular", so I've tried following the advice of [Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) by adding the following to the registry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont /v 000 /t REG_SZ /d Fixedsys
```

I entered "Fixedsys" as the data, as that is displayed as the title of "Fixedsys Regular", but Command Prompt just doesn't want to recognise it as an available font in its properties panel, even after multiple restarts. I have also tried "Fixedsys Regular".

I'm aware that Command Prompt accepts only mono-space fonts for use, but Fixedsys is a mono-space font, to the best of my knowledge.

Any help? :)

[image: Fallout 3 terminal]

Comment: Please see if this question solves your issues http://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-console-font

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

download and install this version of Fixedsys

http://host-a.net/u/mrbubl3s/fixedsys.ttf

The one that ships with windows is a .fon type and the console is VERY picky about what it will take.  That is the whole reason it was made so difficult to change the fonts available in the terminal in the first place.  The file form the download is a .ttf (TrueTypeFont) and will work.  Also, there is no need to restart before checking to see if console has accepted the font.  Just go to properties and check right away after editing the registry.

Comment: What value do I give to `000`? `Fixedsys` didn't work.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

The console *only* accepts fixed width fonts.  So if the font you are trying to use is not fixed width, it wont work.

See this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This font looks close enough to me: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Share+Tech+Mono