# windows CLI looking like ubuntu terminal

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, shell

How can I make my windows 7 command line interface to look like the terminal in Ubuntu ?

Comment: what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "looking like", is it only a matter of appearance, or do you want the same functions?

Comment: I am looking for appearance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The win32 console does not support ANSI escape sequences to color prompts, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you will get is using the free [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) application off SourceForge. Here's a recent Scott Hanselman [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) about customising it. If you grab the free Ubuntu fonts and use the monospaced one for the console, it'll look even more like the Ubuntu shell.

This software works by redirecting output from CMD.EXE, so you won't have colour in the sense that an Ubuntu shell could. To attack that problem, you could use the free CMD.EXE alternative [TCC LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html) and make Console run that instead of CMD.EXE.

Doing all that might get you something similar in terms of looks.

[image]

Comment: Since the answer above, a new solution to this has arrived in the form of the excellent CmdEr (http://bliker.github.io/cmder/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I am changing my answer.

You can change the terminals colors by opening up a command prompt and right clicking the c:\ icon on the top left of the title bar.  Select "defaults" and select the foreground/background color of your choice.

You can also change the fonts in the command shell.  Follow these [instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-console-font) on how to do it.

Comment: Thansk but I have that, I just want it to look like the terminal, like fonts and color & stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Windows CMD customization is very limited.
As an alternative you can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (but it will not have cmd like commands by default).

> A collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment
>   for Windows.

Comment: He doesn't want Linux commands, he wants Linux appearance.

Comment: @AlanB Thanks for pointing. I missed the point completely.