# My Windows console lacks the default font size

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, console

For some reason, my Windows 7 x64 (7601) console font changed to some small unreadable size, and when I try to set it back (in Default or Properties), the default font size, i.e. 8x12, is not present there. There are only sizes like 8x8, 7x12, and all the others, but the 8x12 size is simply removed from there. How can I get it back? Can I set the size somewhere in the registry?

Edit: It happened after I changed the system DPI to some other value and back. Then the console size went down to 4x6.

Comment: Can you be more precise with the Windows Version? and is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui Ah, sorry, added.

Comment: Check here maybe it helps http://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-xp-console-font

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui Thanks, but I am afraid that is for a TrueType font to add it to the list. The default bitmap font is there, just the size option. Hmm, could the font file be corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the same issue [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/312386-cant-change-cmd-exe-settings-default.html), and it was apparently solved by changing the system locale to English and back. I did that and it worked, now 8x12 is back there again.

Here is my registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\Nls]
"00000412"=""
"00000804"=""
"00000411"=""
"00000409"=""
"00000404"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\RasterFonts]
"woafont"="dosapp.fon"
"CGA40WOA.FON"="CGA40WOA.FON"
"CGA80WOA.FON"="CGA80WOA.FON"
"EGA40WOA.FON"="EGA40WOA.FON"
"EGA80WOA.FON"="EGA80WOA.FON"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont]
"949"="*굴림체"
"0"="Lucida Console"
"950"="*細明體"
"932"="*ＭＳ ゴシック"
"936"="*新宋体"
"00"="Consolas"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
"ColorTable01"=dword:00800000
"ColorTable02"=dword:00008000
"ColorTable03"=dword:00808000
"ColorTable04"=dword:00000080
"ColorTable05"=dword:00800080
"ColorTable06"=dword:00008080
"ColorTable07"=dword:00c0c0c0
"ColorTable08"=dword:00808080
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable10"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable12"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable14"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
"CursorSize"=dword:00000019
"EnableColorSelection"=dword:00000000
"ExtendedEditKey"=dword:00000000
"ExtendedEditKeyCustom"=dword:00000000
"FontFamily"=dword:00000000
"FontSize"=dword:00000000
"FontWeight"=dword:00000000
"FullScreen"=dword:00000000
"HistoryBufferSize"=dword:00000032
"HistoryNoDup"=dword:00000000
"InsertMode"=dword:00000001
"LoadConIme"=dword:00000001
"NumberOfHistoryBuffers"=dword:00000004
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f5
"QuickEdit"=dword:00000000
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:012c0050
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000007
"TrimLeadingZeros"=dword:00000000
"WindowSize"=dword:00190050
"WordDelimiters"=dword:00000000
"CurrentPage"=dword:00000001
"FaceName"=""
```

Comment: Worked after relogging. Thank you my past self for help! 

Answer (score 0):

The Raster Font (not TruType Fonts) issue, it would be due to missing system file(s):

1. Press **Win + R**
2. Type **sfc /scannow** (requires admin rights)
3. Restart your system

Now check again, whether your font size was restored or not