# Changing the font of console

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, fonts

I have developed a console application with Java. Now I am distributing it to the users who do not have administrator privileges. Users will run the program in Windows 7 or later. They will start the program by double clicking to a .bat file. I need that bat file, because I have to add some variables to the path before the program starts. In addition, I need to show some Turkish characters (such as ğ, ü) in console. Therefore, I change encoding to the 65001 or 857. However, the console's default font is set to "raster font" that cannot show Turkish characters. So, I wonder if there is a programmatic way of changing the font or not in bat file or not.

Actually, I have encountered a solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548731/2979477, but I am looking for another way that do not use a .lnk shortcut, because I do not want users to suppose that it is a shortcut and can be deleted.

I also know the post in this link: [How to change the Windows XP console font?](https://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-xp-console-font), but I do not want to change the font permanently. Instead, I want it to be like a session-based.

So, I am open to any kind of solutions that I can change font in the batch file. By the way this is my bat file:

```
@echo off
set "PATH=C:\Users\some_path;%PATH%"
chcp 857
title My Program
color 0A
mode con: cols=100 lines=45
REM run my java program
```